# How to set a permanent buffer size for file transfers

Tags: filemanager, transfer, cache

I have read other posts that address the problem of excessive RAM usage for buffering, during huge file transfers. I know about `nocache` etc.

What I'd like to ask is whether there's a way to actually define a certain buffer size, for example 1G, for file transfers, so that the system would never exceed it under any circumstances, no matter what app we use to actually do those transfers. I think that using no buffer at all is not the best thing we could do.

A preset system-wide buffer size so that we can use any File Manager for file transferring would be great. Can this be done?